# Which fictional universes make good examples for formal analysis?

Tags: worldbuilding-resources

I am writing a paper on a way to apply category theory ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category_theory), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/category%20theory)) to literary analysis. My plan is to explain allegories ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allegory_(mathematics)), [nLab](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/allegory)) as a way of formalizing the structure in fictional universes, and to use examples from well-known fictional universes in order to make otherwise-abstract ideas concrete.

When I was workshopping this paper, I started by explaining concepts to friends by telling little stories with nonce fictional universes. However, I quickly found myself pushed against the problem of reality's endless details intruding into the fridge logic ([Tropes](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/FridgeLogic)) of my stories; the problem of which logic belongs in which universe is the entire problem I'm trying to address! I switched to Arda/Middle-Earth, Harry Potter, Marvel Cinematic, and other popular universes; and that works well enough informally and in-person. However, I could not afford to properly license those fictional universes, and I would need more than fair use in order to use them as foundational features of my work. (Also, ew? I would be disgusted and ashamed to put branding on mathematics. Rather, I want to mathematically analyze branded media.)

Currently I am using the fact that every person already has a logical universe which they might believe describes the real world around them. The map-territory distinction ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map%E2%80%93territory_relation)) and mind projection fallacy ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_projection_fallacy)) explain that these universes are always fictional, so they should be usable. From this, I have chosen common objects like trees as examples of fictional objects which can be described relationally. However, this feels more like an elegant hack than a complete solution. **Are there freely-usable fictional universes which are good venues for literary analysis?**

This is a worldbuilding question because somebody has to build the logic for each of the fictional universes used.

I'm aware of Jenny Everywhere ([WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jenny_Everywhere)) and intend to examine her in order to explain quantifying over all universes. However, I want to analyze settings too.

Comment: You might want to ask this again on Academia.SE or SciFi.SE. WB.SE is for worldbuilding, i.e. the process of making **new** fictional worlds. That said, you might want to check out Asimov's *Foundation Universe*; IIRC it's free to use.

Comment: This isn't an academic paper and it's not limited to science fiction. I suppose, category-theoretically, I'm asking about a "free fictional universe generated by a story" and thus I'm asking for a well-known story which shows off all of the logical features. In the past, though, I've been burdened by filling out the fridge logic, and I realize that this will *always* be a problem because reality is endlessly detailed and we foolishly copy reality's logic into every story by default.

Comment: If you're looking for "free fictional universe generated by a story" then you're not building a fictional world. You're analyzing an existing fictional world.

Comment: @sphennings A delightful philosophical question! Do categories spring into existence simply because we declare them? Or are the categories already there, waiting for us to describe them properly? The same question applies to fictional universes. I don't want to take a strong opinion on the answer.

Comment: @Corbin It seems like you're doing some interesting work but if you're not asking a question about building a fictional world then this site isn't the right place to be asking it.

Comment: Fair enough. I fear that there's no better place for this, so I'm going to go ahead and close the question. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I am familiar with the mathematics of category theory. Feel free to check my other SE accounts ;). However I do not understand what you are trying to achieve here. Some examples are welcome.

Comment: You can of course mention the MCU and Harry Potter here all you want, to give examples of what you are trying to explain

Comment: Fictional universes are allegories, adaptations are adjoint functors, subplots are full subcategories, simplifications are e.w. subcategories, alternate universes are functors in general; and that's just the basics needed to explain how deconstruction and multiverses work. It's all very boring obvious stuff if we ask how logic in one world is mapped into logic in another world: Every relation must map, including the compositions.

Comment: I am not at all certain that I understand why you think that you need a license in order to write a literary critique or analysis of a work. You most certainly do not. (For example, look in Wikipedia for articles about works published in the last 100 years; you will find very many.) You may want to ask on [Law.SE](https://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @Corbin I still don't understand. What is the simplest concrete example you can think of? i.e a particular fictional universe and category theoretic gizmo?

Comment: As far asI know, transformative use is a copyright exception, as is some kind of reference/analysis (vs use). Are you sure you have a problem....?

Comment: Maybe this should be asked on WB Meta?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the Author of the query requested that it be closed: *Fair enough. I fear that there's no better place for this, so I'm going to go ahead and close the question.*

Answer (score 3):

**Some Examples.**

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve. Remember you only need to license works and pay royalties if you want to profit from your paper. **(Note: I have been told this is untrue and I am not a lawyer.)** Even then there is a limited amount of "fair use" that might allow you to mention many different copyrighted universes, provided you do not spend much time on each. I am not an expert on the specifics.

That said some examples of fictional universes that are now public domain are most of the **Sherlock Holmes** stories, anything by **Charles Dickens** or **William Shakespeare**, and the entirety of **Ancient Greek, Norse, and Egyptian  Mythology.** Though the latter are somewhat tricky since there are many versions of each story.

The key words to search online are **off copyright** and **public domain**. Many of the books on the English Literature curriculum are now public domain.

Comment: *"You only need to license works and pay royalties if you want to profit from your paper":* this is **false** in any country I can think of. But then, I am not a lawyer; and after reading this, I am absolutely certain that you also are not a lawyer. Please do not give incorrect legal advice.

Comment: @AlexP Not a lawyer no. What are the rules for mentioning licensed works not for profit?

Comment: As far as I know one is allowed to *mention* and refer to whatever they like. What one is not allowed to do is to republish or distribute copyrighted works or parts of copyrighted works. (There are some rules about mentioning names which are trademarks, but those rules essentially say that when using such names one must use them to refer to the thing which is actually the object of the trademark and not to something else which may be confused with the real thing.) So, describing the plot *in your own words*, making a list of characters, listing the tropes etc. is allowed.

Comment: For example, I may write and publish, for free or for money, a review of the Stack Exchange network, mentioning it by name and mentioning the various sites it consists of. But I am not allowed to pick up the Stack Exchange logo and re-use it in my work without a license; and I am not allowed to set up an interactive web site and call it Stack Exchange.

Comment: @AlexP Okay I have added a note that no one should listen to what I say about copyright law.

Comment: To summarize in a way that ties back to my question: Of course I can publish analyses of popular works using my techniques, and I intend to do that. What I cannot do is use popular characters as foundational bedrock for justifying why my techniques work. Compare "a whatever analysis of Marvel characters" vs. "Marvel presents: Which character embodies a whatever philosophy?"

Answer (score 3):

### Examples of "well-known fictional universes" which are free to use

(All links in this answer go to Wikipedia. All the mentioned works are free to use. The full text of the works mentioned in this answer is widely available on the Internet, usually in multiple editions. For example, [Project Gutenberg](https://gutenberg.org) has most of them.)

- Let's begin with the revered ancestor of fictional universes, the Homeric world.

  Homer's [*Iliad*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iliad) and [*Odyssey*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Odyssey%5D) are free to use. The same fictional universe is shared with [Euripides](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euripides)'s [*Orestia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oresteia) trilogy and the separate plays [*Iphigenia in Aulis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphigenia_in_Aulis), [*Iphigenia in Tauris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphigenia_in_Tauris) and [*Electra*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electra_(Euripides_play)). [Sophocles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophocles) also wrote plays set in this universe.

  At the end of the first century BCE, [Virgil](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virgil) wrote the [*Aeneid*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeneid), a very well known and very well received sequel.

  In more modern times, [Jacques Offenbach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacques_Offenbach) wrote the immortal [*Belle Hélène*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_belle_H%C3%A9l%C3%A8ne) comic opera (on a book by his trusted collaborators Henri Meilhac and Ludovic Halévy).

  Apply your analysis to the *Odyssey*. It has everything; compelling plot, complex characters, layered stories, awesome imagery.
- Let's also mention the *other* grand-daddy of fictional universes, the Old Testament. (A well-known sequel was written in the first centuries of the common era.) Maybe a little bit drier than the Homeric world, nevertheless it has powerful characters, straight-up magic, battles, love stories and so on.

  Please note that the Old and New Testaments are more than just collection fictional stories; they are foundational texts for the religions of billions of people. (I am one of them.) Care must be exercised when re-using the stories.
- Then in the Middle Ages we have the famous chivalric romances. For example, Thomas Malory's [*Morte d'Arthur*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Le_Morte_d%27Arthur). It contains a vast fictional universe, populated with well known characters such as Merlin the Magician and that most complex enchantress [Morgan Le Fay](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morgan_le_Fay). Plus of course the French [*chansons de geste*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chanson_de_geste) and the the nordic sagas, for example, [Njall's Saga](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nj%C3%A1ls_saga) or the [Heimskringla](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heimskringla).
- And then of course are the [*One Thousand and One Nights*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/One_Thousand_and_One_Nights). Some of the stories are short, but several are long, complex and intricate. Some of the characters have passed into public consciousness, such as Haroun al Rashid, his vizier Jafar, Sindbad the Sailor, Ali Baba or Aladdin (the last two being "extras" added by the French translator Antoine Galland.) Plus the famous framing device, with Scheherazade, king Shahryar and so on.
- Since this is getting long, let's skip to modern fictional universes. You cannot get a more intricate fictional universe than Alexandre Dumas's [*Three Musketeers*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Three_Musketeers) trilogy, or Eugene Sue's [*Mysteries of Paris*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mysteries_of_Paris), or John Galsworthy's [*Forsyte Saga*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Forsyte_Saga), or Anthony Trollope's [*Palliser*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Palliser_novels) novels.

  If you prefer lighter weight stuff, you can freely use H. Ridder Haggard's [Allan Quatermain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Allan_Quatermain) universe, which even has an early example of cross-over with [*She*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She:_A_History_of_Adventure).

  If you prefer *apparently* lightweight stuff which would be a great pleasure to unravel, consider Kipling's [*Jungle Books*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Jungle_Book).
- Finally, I have to mention explicitly [shared universes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shared_universe), of which the Eric Flint's [1632](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1632_series) is a great example.
- All in all, Project Gutenberg and [Archive.org](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1632_series) are your friends, with tens and hundreds of thousands of books, free to read, free to reuse, free to transform.

P.S. Other sprawling fictional universes which anybody is free to re-use to their heart's content: Dumas's [Count of Monte-Cristo](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Count_of_Monte_Cristo); Ponson du Terrail's [Rocambole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rocambole_(character)); Maurice Leblanc's [Arsène Lupin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ars%C3%A8ne_Lupin); Conan Doyle's [Sherlock Holmes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sherlock_Holmes); Zévaco's [knights Pardaillan](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pardaillan); Balzac's [*Comédie humaine*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/La_Com%C3%A9die_humaine); Zola's [Rougon-Macquarts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Les_Rougon-Macquart); Anthony Hope's [*Ruritania*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruritania); and so on.

Comment: (*Gets all puffed up and uppity*) I must protest! The Old Testament is not "fictional"! (*De-puffs*) - At least, not in the minds of the billion+ Christians around the world. I completely understand why many people--atheists or otherwise--might be comfortable referring to the bible, in whole or in part, as fiction, but it doesn't take a lot of effort to differentiate it from the deliberate works of fiction that you're listing in your post. Just a thought :)

Comment: @Qami: I will edit the answer to make it clear that the O.T. and N.T. are more than fiction. (And of those billions of Christians, only a small subset believe that the stories are not fictional. We the vast majority believe that the stories tell a fundamental truth transcending petty historical reality. I always forget that there are some churches in America which teach that for real in real history there was a magicking contest between the magicians of an anonymous Pharaoh and the magicians of the Hebrews.)

Comment: Fair point! I suspect there's something of a gradient--there's young-earth ideologies on one end who would attempt to interpret each story, verse and number completely literally; something perhaps closer to your interpretation on the other, and various middle perspectives which would take many of the stories as allegorical or exaggerated but feel that Christianity does require a literally crucified-and-risen Jesus.

Comment: @Qami: That depends on what is to be understood by a literal crucified and risen Jesus; and it certainly does not depend on the different accounts being all literally true in all details, which they obviously cannot be. (Favorite example: there are two different and incompatible genealogies of Jesus, both tracing his descent through Joseph, *who crucially was not his father*, and completely ignoring the descent of Mary, who actually *was* his mother.)

Comment: Doesn't matter what your own religious persuasion is, but it is best practice not to be a tick  about other people's religious scriptures of any kind. The disingenuous "clarification" just adds insult to insult. -1 for behaving boorishly!

Comment: @Qami: This is a great example of missing my goal: I am looking for fictional universes which are *logically consistent*, which excludes the Bible, the Odyssey, and most other millennia-old works. The best example so far is the world of Scheherezade, which has unusually high logical consistency due to its frame narrative.

Comment: @Corbin: well, this isn't the place for me to take your bait. ;) But I do admire/am interested by the sound of the project you're working on. Best of luck, both in finding a good world to work with and in hashing out your theory application!

Answer (score 2):

Well, I can't say I understood what it is you're going on about --- I'm certain all the words were English, but have no idea what the end result is supposed to mean --- but I do grasp the essence of the question.

It seems like you're looking for a private, non-commercial yet somewhat well-known fictional world to analyse. At the risk of seeming too forward, mine might fit the bill. I've been working on it long enough that worldbuilding questions are never "can I do this" or even "how is this so" but almost always "why is it that way", "what does it mean" and "who's behind it". Even "does it really matter after all".

I've got a reasonable good comprehension of the place and can (and often have) done fairly deep worldbuilding on the fly. I can answer like a native, if you will, without having to sit down and ponder twenty different basic & underlying concepts that I haven't yet discovered. There may also be enough written material --- in-world works, external data, and stories set in the world --- that you could sift through. Also, I know quite a bit about trees. Enough to know they're not to be entirely trusted. Let alone hugged.

Comment: I've been down this path; I have good friends who worldbuild, and I have examined several different RP universes. The problem is the same as when I write the stories: reality is endlessly detailed and we have worked out most of the issues with science, so that a storyteller is forced to endlessly import those details wholesale or simply admit logical defeat. This is why I suggested that the real world as a fictional universe is an elegant hack; it has physical justification and results in a decent communication channel full of example relations, like trees.

Answer (score 1):

**Children's literature.**

https://www.loc.gov/free-to-use/classic-childrens-books/

[image: mother goods]

For the sake of simplicity.  They are many, are shorter and have fewer variables to consider.

If you leave out Alice in Wonderland.